# Location based screen, location unavailable

Tags: location-service, mobile-application

I am working on a section of my app that requires the users location to pull data from an API.

Given a scenario where the location is unavailable to the app, what would you guys suggest?

A couple of ideas I had were:

- Prompt to enable location services if unavailable (what about devices without GPS)
- Prompt user to select location (either by drag/drop or predefined list)

Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The granularity of detail in an answer probably depends on the desired accuracy of the location needed for your app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending upon the usage of the application you might want to give a **manual location entry as a default feature** regardless of GPS availability. Say your app shows nearby restaurants, the user might want to see 'nearby' ones to his destination rather than his current location.

That being said, ideally, you would have an **alert dialog box with 'settings/location services' and 'cancel' buttons** on it so if the user selects to enable settings he can launch the menu from the app itself, otherwise he can cancel and move on.

What kind of app is it that you're developing which uses location services and can be installed on a non-gps/feature phone?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how granular you need the location to be, **would the IP address suffice**? You could use this to move the user forward, with a note asking for their actual address if they want for accurate results.